# Issue with persisting session attributes after Torii authentication with ember-simple-auth

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth, ember-cli-rails

I'm following `ember-simple-auth` [dummy app](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/tests/dummy/app/authenticators/torii.js) to implement authentication with `torii`. Everything works, and the app authenticates, but it fails to persist additional attributes returned from the server into `data.authenticated`. Just as the authentication method expects, I return a promise from the authenticator method with additional attributes `token` and `email` to be persisted into the session's `data.authenticated`:

```
// ~/frontend/app/authenticators/torii.js

import Ember from 'ember';
import ToriiAuthenticator from 'ember-simple-auth/authenticators/torii';

export default ToriiAuthenticator.extend({
  torii: Ember.inject.service(),

  authenticate() {
    return this._super(...arguments).then((data) => {
      return new Ember.RSVP.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return Ember.$.ajax({
          url: '/token',
          type:     'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          data:     { 'grant_type': 'facebook_auth_code', 'auth_code': data.authorizationCode, redirect_uri: data.redirectUri  }
        }).then(response => {
          Ember.run(() => {
            Ember.Logger.log('response', response); // => {access_token: ".....", provider: "facebook-oauth2", token: "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkI…WxsfQ.xx6fBkwqwm7HeoOpnRWRVCKF71DdIhxyQggcfZ6325s", email: "..@....com"}
            resolve(response);
          });
        }, xhr => {
          Ember.run(() => { reject(xhr.responseJSON || xhr.responseText); });
        });
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Performing the authentication: `this.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:torii', 'facebook-oauth2');` successfully authenticates, but the contents of `data.authenticated` are only `{authenticator: "authenticator:torii", provider: "facebook-oauth2"}` while I would expect it to persist `token` and `email` as well.

In addition to `torii` I also have a `devise` authenticator and it successfully persists additional attributes by default.

I'm using `"ember-simple-auth": "1.1.0",` `ember-data 2.7.0` and `ember 2.7.2` all via `ember-cli-rails`.

**UPDATE 1:** Weirdly, if I include `authenticator: 'authenticator:devise'` in my `'/token'` ajax response from the backend, the `torii` authenticator persists all attributes.